# Shapeless HList with ClassTags

Tags: scala, functional-programming, shapeless

I have a quite simple function that is able to instantiate the class of type C:

```
  def parse[C: ClassTag]: C = implicitly[ClassTag[C]].runtimeClass.getCanonicalName match {
          case "int" ⇒ 10.asInstanceOf[C]
          case "double" ⇒ 10d.asInstanceOf[C]
          case "java.lang.String" ⇒ "qwerty".asInstanceOf[C]
    }

       parse[Int] // res0: Int = 10
       parse[Double] // res1: Double = 10.0
       parse[String] // res2: qwerty = String
```

I'd like to introduce second function:

```
def parseAll[T <: HList]: T = ???
```

And use it as follows:

```
val defaults: Int :: Double :: String :: HNil = parseAll[Int :: Double :: String :: HNil] 
// res3: shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Double,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]] = 10 :: 10.0 :: qwerty :: HNil
```

Any ideas how can I implement such function?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with shapeless and not the best person to answer. But since no one is answering I recommend to search for `UnaryTCConstraint`. Seems that it's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define [type class](https://blog.scalac.io/2017/04/19/typeclasses-in-scala.html) `ParseAll`:

```
  import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil}
  import scala.reflect.ClassTag

  def parse[C: ClassTag]: C = implicitly[ClassTag[C]].runtimeClass.getCanonicalName match {
    case "int" ⇒ 10.asInstanceOf[C]
    case "double" ⇒ 10d.asInstanceOf[C]
    case "java.lang.String" ⇒ "qwerty".asInstanceOf[C]
  }

  def parseAll[T <: HList](implicit p: ParseAll[T]): T = p.apply

  trait ParseAll[T <: HList] {
    def apply: T
  }

  object ParseAll {
    implicit def hCons[H: ClassTag, T <: HList](implicit p: ParseAll[T]): ParseAll[H :: T] = new ParseAll[H :: T] {
      override def apply: H :: T = parse[H] :: p.apply
    }

    implicit val hNil: ParseAll[HNil] = new ParseAll[HNil] {
      override def apply: HNil = HNil
    }
  }

  parseAll[Int :: Double :: String :: HNil] // 10 :: 10.0 :: "qwerty" :: HNil
```

---

Actually you can do this without reflection:

```
  import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil}

  def parse[C](implicit p: Parse[C]): C = p.apply

  trait Parse[C] {
    def apply: C
  }

  object Parse {
    implicit val int: Parse[Int] = new Parse[Int] {
      override def apply: Int = 10
    }

    implicit val double: Parse[Double] = new Parse[Double] {
      override def apply: Double = 10.0
    }

    implicit val string: Parse[String] = new Parse[String] {
      override def apply: String = "qwerty"
    }
  }

  def parseAll[T <: HList](implicit p: ParseAll[T]): T = p.apply

  trait ParseAll[T <: HList] {
    def apply: T
  }

  object ParseAll {
    implicit def hCons[H, T <: HList](implicit parse: Parse[H], parseAll: ParseAll[T]): ParseAll[H :: T] = new ParseAll[H :: T] {
      override def apply: H :: T = parse.apply :: parseAll.apply
    }

    implicit def hNil: ParseAll[HNil] = new ParseAll[HNil] {
      override val apply: HNil = HNil
    }
  }

  parseAll[Int :: Double :: String :: HNil] // 10 :: 10.0 :: "qwerty" :: HNil
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dmytro, it works.
P.S. I need the ClassTag anyway in my case, `parse` is a third-party function, it was just a simple example.